# Switching CSS class of div on click in Oracle apex

Tags: javascript, html, css, oracle

I have dynamic region rendering HTML code as below:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 mb-30">
                    <div id="'||l_cnt||'" class="package_box" onClick=selectText('||i.PKG_ID||')>
                        <a id="'||i.PKG_ID||'" href="#" class="text_wht" onclick=setDetails('||i.PKG_ID||'); onClick=selectText('||i.PKG_ID||')
                            data-pkgid="'||i.PKG_ID||'" data-price="'||i.OFFERED_PRICE||'" data-pkgname="'||i.PKG_ARB_NAME||'">
                            <img src="'||i.TEMPLATE_IMG||'" class="img-center" onClick=changeClass()>
                        </a>
                        <div class="clearfix pad-15">
                            <h3 class="mt-0"><strong class="pull-left font_arial text-center">'||I.OFFERED_PRICE||'<br><span class="text_12 text_blck">SAR</span></strong>'||i.PKG_ARB_NAME||'</h3>
                            <div class="clear pad-5"></div>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-rounded pull-left"><span class="font_arial">عدد الوجبات : '||I.NO_OF_MEALS||'</span> </button>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-rounded btn-border" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".product-img'||i.PKG_ID||'">التفاصيل</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I want to switch `class="package_box"` to `class="package_box active"` when the user clicks on a img inside the div.

I am using the JS function below, but it is not working:

```
function changeClass() {
      var div = document.getElementsByClassName("package_box"); 
     document.getElementById("div").className = "package_box active";   
}
```

How do I toggle the class using this function when the user clicks on the image?

Comment: How many elements with the class `package_box` will you have?

Comment: There may be multiple elements , as its dynamic region

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
function changeClass() {
  // Listen for the click event on the image.
  this.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    /* Get the target's (img) closest relative up the DOM tree that matches
     * the class ".package_box" and on click, toggle the "active" class
    */
    event.target.closest('.package_box').classList.toggle('active');
  });
}
```

Also, your `onClick` should probably be lowercase and in quotes, e.g. `onclick="changeClass()"`

Test Snippet:

```js
function changeClass() {
  this.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.target.closest('.package_box').classList.toggle('active');
  });
}
```

```css
.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="package_box">
  <div>
    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/0/543/543.jpg?hmac=vkQshP4GPU8JNGicpcjZANqwAY8T7FfIY-WU5khNLiQ" class="img-center" onclick="changeClass()">
  </div>

</div>
```

EDIT:
It's potentially not working on your site, because I realized you are wrapping the image in an `<a>` anchor tag with it's own click event - so the mouse click doesn't reach the image.

You could add the `changeClass()` inside of the `setDetails()` function since the image will always be wrapped in an `a` tag according to your code snippet. And you don't need to add the `changeClass()` to the `onclick` of the image. You can remove that.

```js
function changeClass(img) {
  // Get all the package_box elements
  let package = document.getElementsByClassName('package_box');

  // convert to an array and remove the active class from all of them.
  [...package].forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.classList.remove('active');
  });

  // Add the active class to the one we clicked.
  img.closest('.package_box').classList.add('active');

}

function setDetails() {
  //set details do stuff...
  // Use an event listener to find out which a tag we've clicked and pass the target.
  this.addEventListener('click', changeClass(event.target), false);
}
```

```css
.active {
  background: red;
}

a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="package_box">
  <a href="#" onclick="setDetails()">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" class="img-center">
  </a>

</div>

<div class="package_box">
  <a href="#" onclick="setDetails()">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" class="img-center">
  </a>

</div>

<div class="package_box">
  <a href="#" onclick="setDetails()">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" class="img-center">
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: https://programic-erp.maxapex.net/apex/f?p=155:28 can you run this page and check why the same code is not working

Comment: can you check the same link again , its highlighting all images when i click , i want to highlight only one image on which i click , like `package_box active` will be one at a time other will be replacing with `package_box`

Comment: So you want if you click one, it highlights, if you click another - that one will highlight and the other one will no longer be highlighted? Basically only one should be active at a time?

Comment: @AdeelAslam updated the bottom answer to meet those requirements.

Comment: its looks fix now , thank you , great effort

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your function as below

If you want to only add a new class without removing the existing class

```
function changeClass() {
      $(".package_box").addClass("active");   
}
```

Comment: Its replace the class like this `class="active"` however it should be `package_box active`
https://programic-erp.maxapex.net/apex/f?p=155:28 check this link trying clicking on image